# Capturing multiple phone numbers with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to improve with regex as I'm tired of constantly having to look up existing solutions instead of creating my own. Having a bit of difficulty understanding why this isn't working though:

Trying to extract both phone numbers from the following string (numbers and address are random):

```
+1-541-754-3010 156 Alphand_St. <J Steeve>\n 133, Green, Rd. <E Kustur> NY-56423 ;+1-541-914-3010\n"
```

So I'm using the following expression:

```
 /\+(.+)(?:\s|\b)/
```

These are the matches I'm getting back:

1. 1-541-754-3010 156 Alphand_St.

   1-541-914-3010

So I'm getting the last one correctly, but not the first one. Based on the expression, it should match anything from between a + and a space/boundary. But for some reason it's not stopping at the space after the first number. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: First of all, your regex won't even return the matches you mentioned because you're using a [greedy match](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). Second, you need to understand what a [word boundary (`\b`)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is (note that `-` IS a word boundary). And finally, you shouldn't really be using a [dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) when all you want to match is numbers and hyphens.

Comment: Also, add a language tag and show how you're applying the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the format you provided for the search string, and since you are starting with a literal "+", I would just include the next following string of decimals and separators, like the hyphen:

```
/\+([0-9\-]+)/
```

Your ".+" says to match everything until there's a \s.  However that also includes \s on the way to the \s.

Comment: Oh, I suppose that makes sense. Is there anyway to use .+ up until a specific character? Or to exclude a character from .

Comment: Well, yes there is, with
/\+(.+?)\s/ like spoken about below, the ? will make it lazy and it will try to match as few times as possible.  I would still use searching for decimals like my answer and the one below.

Comment: This (and CertainPerformance's answer as well) might (or might not) be sufficient for the OP's requirements, but be aware that it will also match things like `+----`, for example. @TimBaker Matching phone numbers [isn't that simple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123559/4934172), _specially if you expect to match different formats_. If, however, all you have to match is one format, it might be simpler but you'd need to write something specifically for that format. Example: [`\+\d{1,2}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`](https://regex101.com/r/cHVXgf/1).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that dashes `-` are not word characters, so `\b` will match between, for example, `1-` and `-5` and so on. Also, your current regex is *greedy* - it'll try to match as many characters as it can with the repeated `.`, which is why it goes all the way to the end of the first line (because after the last character in the line matches `\b`). Making it lazy (with `.+?`) wouldn't fix it, though, because then it would terminate right after the `1` in `1-541` (because between `1-` is a word boundary)

Try using a character set of digits and `-` instead:

```
\+([\d-]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/ktbcHJ/1